# How to get client ID of dropdownlist inside gridview in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to access the dropdownlist inside gridview using below code but it throws an error

> Name `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_DropDownList1` is not
>   declared.

```
function combo() {
        $('#<%=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_DropDownList1.ClientID %>').combobox();
        $('#easyui-combobox').combobox('reload');
    }
```

What should be the proper way of retrieving the template field client ID in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `ClientIDMode="Static"` for dropdown so its `ID` will `not change` from what you have set.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlYear ClientIDMode="Static">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This ! I don't sure about ASPX (%) Syntax

```
 function combo() {
        $('#' + <%=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_DropDownList1.ClientID %>).combobox();
        $('#easyui-combobox').combobox('reload');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function combo() {
        $('#' + <%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>).combobox();
        $('#easyui-combobox').combobox('reload');
    }
```

OR

```
function combo() {
        $('[id$=DropDownList1]').combobox();
        $('#easyui-combobox').combobox('reload');
    }
```